# Can we always find matrices $M,N$ such that $\ker(MA+NB) = \ker(A) \cap \ker(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields

Suppose $A,B$ are $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients in a field $\mathbb{F}$. Is it always possible to find $n\times n$ matrices $M,N$ with coefficients in the same field such that $$\ker(MA+NB) = \ker(A)\cap \ker(B)?$$ If $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ then we can set $M = A^T, N = B^T$ and then the result follows because $$A^TAv + B^TBv = 0 \implies 0 = \langle v, A^TAv + B^TBv\rangle $$ $$= \langle v, A^TAv\rangle + \langle v,B^TBv\rangle = \|Av\|^2 + \|Bv\|^2 $$ which immediately tells us that $Av = Bv = 0$ (where the inner products are the normal dot product and sesquilinear products on $\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{C}^n$ depending on if we are working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).

Notably, this approach catastrophically fails over fields not equal to $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ as for example we can have $$A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \implies A^TA = 0$$ if you are working over $\mathbb{F}_2$. Is it still possible to find $M,N$ despite the fact that this "obvious guess" fails?

Comment: My hunch is that this is already possible with $M$ and $N$ being scalar multiples of the identity matrix. Note that this assertion is equivalent to the following: if $S$ and $T$ are linear transformations (not identically zero) on a finite-dimensional $\Bbb F$-vector space whose kernels are disjoint, then there exists $\alpha\in\Bbb F$ such that $S+\alpha T$ is invertible. (change from matrices to linear transformations, then mod the vector space out by the intersection of their kernels) Is this a true/provable statement?

Comment: @GregMartin: I'm pretty sure that statement fails over F2 (possibly over bigger finite characteristics too but haven't thought about it much): take the 4x4 matrix A which is the identity but the first column is all zeros and B to be the identity but the second column is all zeros. Then A,B only share the origin in their kernel but A is not invertible and A+B is not invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In principle, since $\ker A\cap\ker B=\ker\pmatrix{A\\ B}$, any matrix $\pmatrix{M&N}\in\mathbb F^{n\times2n}$ that maps the range of $\pmatrix{A\\ B}$ to a subspace of the same dimension will do the job.

E.g., suppose $\pmatrix{A\\ B}$ has rank $r>0$. Let $UV$ be its [rank factorisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization), where $U\in\mathbb F^{2n\times r}$. Let $T\in\mathbb F^{r\times 2n}$ be a left inverse of $U$. Then
$$
\ker\left(\pmatrix{T\\ 0_{(n-r)\times 2n}}UV\right)=\ker(TUV)=\ker(I_rV)=\ker(V)\subseteq\ker(UV)\subseteq\ker(TUV).
$$
Therefore all set inclusions above are equalities. Now put $\pmatrix{M&N}=\pmatrix{T\\ 0_{(n-r)\times 2n}}$ and we are done.

(In the example above, since $UV$ is a rank factorisation, the range of $UV$ is the precisely range of $U$. As $T$ is a left inverse of $U$, it maps the range of $U$ to a subspace of the same dimension.)

Comment: So just to be clear, when you define $M,N$ you just chop the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}T \\\ 0_{(n-r)\times 2n} \end{pmatrix}$ down the middle?

Comment: @IskyMathews Yes.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Great Answer. Another idea is to reduce your matrix $(A^t,B^t)^t$ with a invertible matrix $R_{2n\times 2n}$, i.e., $R(A^t,B^t)^t$ is in RREF. Then You pick the first n rows of $R$ to form $(M,N)$. Notice that $(M,N)(A^t,B^t)^t$ has rank $r$. Hence its nullity coincides with the dimension of $\ker(A)\cap\ker(B)$ which is a subspace of the Kernel of $(M,N)(A^t,B^t)^t=MA+NB$.